# Mock the internals of a thunk

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-native, react-native-navigation

This is a test I'm running:

```
it('dispatches the logout action', () => {
   const store = mockStore({});

   store.dispatch(logout()); // TODO: logout() has a function in its payload that gives an error
   const expectedActions = store.getActions();
   expect(expectedActions).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

It's giving me the following error: (using this library: https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation)

```
Navigation.getRegisteredScreen: login used but not yet registered
```

The problem is that the logout() action dispatches a thunk (async) that calls `Navigation.startSingleScreenApp`. I somehow need to mock this Navigation class OR mock the entire logout() action.

I've tried several things:

```
loginService.logout = jest.fn();
jest.spyOn(Navigation, 'startSingleScreenApp');
```

But none of these seem to work.

Can anyone help me? I'm familiar with mocking but I'm clueless here.

Comment: It would be helpful to look at the definition of `logout()`. You could fake the implementation of all the methods called within logout(). I'm not sure what the return value of startSingleScreenApp is, but you could do `jest.spyOn(Navigation, 'startSingleScreenApp').mockImplementation(() => { /* do something fake */ });`

Comment: Adding .mockImplementation did the trick. Put it in a separate answer and I'll accept it!

I was used to the Jasmine way of mocking, where you had to say `.and.callthrough` to actually call the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful to look at the definition of `logout()`. You could fake the implementation of all the methods called within `logout()`. I'm not sure what the return value of startSingleScreenApp is, but you could do:

```
jest.spyOn(Navigation, 'startSingleScreenApp').mockImplementation(() => {
  /* do something fake */
});
```